# Display node data in a blank page

Tags: 7, entities

Is it possible to display a set of nodes and display it on a blank page without the default template around it? This node data is meant for printing and I want it to display on the screen as it would appear on a printout.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should look at the [Printer, email and PDF versions](https://drupal.org/project/print) module. It is designed to create alternate versions of your pages for print and documentation purposes. It allows you to specify different template files for the output, and you can customize it any way you wish.